# Need to add hero slider in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

we need to add hero slider in our sharepoint portal website, please let us know if there is any tutorial there please. thanks.

Also can we add it on publishing site and on team site, what are possible ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of vague, but knowing sharepoint super users I understand.

It seems a common way to do it without deploying is using a content query web part and a image library.

Here is a similar [question](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/79f8b4a7-f99e-4a32-998d-e542e1beb833/create-jquery-slide-showing-using-content-editor-webpart-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious).

I think this is a good place to start: [JQuery Slider](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/12/rotating-banner-sharepoint-jquery.html).

If you are a developer and can deploy Sandbox or Farm solutions, there are more options.